# A name for this kind of lax 2-limit

Tags: ct.category-theory, terminology

Consider the following statement of a universal property in a 2-category:
Consider the situation of lax squares:

[image: lax square]

then what is the name for a universal object $\ell$ equipped with a lax square over the cospan $X\to S \leftarrow S'$ such that in the lax square above, there exists a unique dotted map $X\to \ell$, and a unique 2-cell $(X'\to \ell \to X) \Rightarrow (X'\to X)$ as in the diagram

[image: lax factorization]

such that the pasting composite of the 2-cells is equal to the 2-cell we started with?

(sorry for the images, Mathjax had some trouble making this diagram reasonable)

Does it have a name?  It's describing something like a 'lax base change', but it's not really a comma object.

Bonus question: Is there a nice and simple construction of this thing in Cat?

Comment: In the 2nd diagram, it should be $X'$ in the  top left corner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that such constructions need not exist. In Cat, let $S$ be terminal. Then any choice of the 2-morphism with 0-domain $X’$, which you assume to exist uniquely, is as good as any other, the pasting always giving the unique 2-morphism with 0-codomain $S=*$.

To explain this, it looks to me as if you are asking precisely that the lax limit of the arrow $\ell\to X$ should be the comma object of the original span. But not every projection out of a comma object factors through a projection out of the limit. Indeed, thinking again of $S=*$, the comma object is $X\times S’$and the projection $X\times S’\to X$ need not factor this way, unless I’m missing something-for instance try $X$ an arrow and $S’$ discrete.

Comment: I figured it might exist because Cat is 2-complete and you can see this thing as some kind of 2-Kan extension of a certain shape of 2-diagram, but I guess that doesn't work the same way in 2-category land.